# What is a semaphore wait?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I got the following error in my MariaDB 10.x `hostname.err` log:

```
InnoDB: ###### Diagnostic info printed to the standard error stream
InnoDB: Error: semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds
InnoDB: We intentionally crash the server, because it appears to be hung.
```

Can someone please explain (as simply as possible ;-D) what a "semaphore wait" is within the context of MySQL/MariaDB?

All I could gather from Mr. Google is that they are "related to internal synchronization between threads in mysqld"

Comment: Scroll back in your error log.  There should have been some prior warnings, such as `--Thread %lu has waited at %s line %lu for %.2f seconds the semaphore:` or `InnoDB: Pending preads %lu, pwrites %lu`.   See anything?  Also, what specific version of MariaDB 10.x.x are you running?  The two most obvious causes of this are defective hardware -- such as a hard drive that is near failure but not actually returning errors because reads and/or writes eventually succeed but extremely slowly... or a bug in the server daemon itself causing a hang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semaphores throttle access to a resource.  If it's not available a process has to wait until it is.  Very long waits can signal that you have a deadlock situation and something needs to be killed to break it up.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332765/lock-mutex-semaphore-whats-the-difference

> A lock allows only one thread to enter the part that's locked and the
>   lock is not shared with any other processes.
>
> A mutex is the same as a lock but it can be system wide (shared by
>   multiple processes).
>
> A semaphore does the same as a mutex but allows x number of threads to
>   enter, this can be used for example to limit the number of cpu, io or
>   ram intensive tasks running at the same time.